# SQL Move Attribute to another table

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

There are 2 tables. Person and Account. There is a 1:n dependency (via ID) so a person could have n accounts. The Person has an email adress. The change should be, that the email adress will be an attribute in Account Table.
So i created a new attribute email for the account.

How can i move or copy all the email address values from the person to the account and also if a person has 2 accounts, that the email address is copied or moved to both accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way

```
UPDATE account a
   SET email = 
(
  SELECT email 
    FROM person
   WHERE person_id = a.person_id
)
 WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT * 
    FROM person
   WHERE person_id = a.person_id
);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6d90c/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no need to do such copy task.
Its always better to maintain a Primary Key & Foreign key in table.

Still if you want to copy, try something like this.

```
SELECT TMP.EMAIL INTO ACCOUNT AS 'A' FROM 
(SELECT P.EMAIL FROM PERSON AS 'P') AS TMP
WHERE A.ID = P.ID
```

Hope, this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for me worked the following:

`UPDATE
    (SELECT * FROM PERSON p JOIN ACCOUNT a ON a.ID=p.ID) t
SET
    t.PRIMARYEMAIL = t.EMAIL
WHERE
    t.EMAIL IS NOT NULL`